# Can I use mylyn with task branches in svn?

Tags: eclipse, mylyn

Background: We use Python, and pydev makes Eclipse somewhat attractive. We use Jira to track issues. Each jira issue generally gets its own branch in svn.

Mylyn is supposed to manage tasks and task state (knowing which files need to be opened, etc.), but I cannot wrap my head around how I would use it in this situation. Would I have to switch branches manually before (or after?) switching tasks?

Coming from emacs desktop and separate directories for separate branch checkouts, which makes remembering what resources are in play easy (but has other limitations).